# Opencv only process the parts of image

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to make a negative transformation for the image which is a very simple program.

But when I run the program. I want to transform all of the pixels in the image, but only 1/3 parts of that are processed. I don't make sure where is wrong. all the code I followed the book. But the result is different.

I think there is something wrong about the columns, but when I change the value of I.cols in negativeImage function with the actual value of image. the output still keep the same. only 1/3 parts of image are processed. If I 3 times the I.cols all of the pixels in the iamge could be processed.

```
vector<uchar> getNegativeLUT() {
vector<uchar> LUT(256, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    LUT[i] = (uchar)(255 - i);
return LUT;
}

void negativeImage(Mat& I) {
vector<uchar> LUT = getNegativeLUT();
for (int i = 0; i < I.rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j <  I.cols; ++j) {
        I.at<uchar>(i, j) = LUT[I.at<uchar>(i, j)];
        //stack overflow
    }   
  }
}

int main() {
Mat image = imread("1.png");
Mat processed_image2 = image.clone();
negativeImage(processed_image2);
printf("%d", image.cols);

imshow("Input Image", image);
imshow("Negative Image", processed_image2);
waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vekZQ.jpg)

Comment: try image.cloneTo(processed_image2) instead of image.clone()

Comment: You're working as if the image was a CV_8UC1 (grayscale), but it's actually CV_8UC3 (color BGR). So either work on a grayscale image: `Mat image = imread("1.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);`, or correct your `negativeImage` to work on 3 channels. May I ask why you don't simply: `Mat processed_image = ~image;` ?

Comment: use .at<cv::Vec3b> to access 3-channel 8 bit pe channel pixel (like standard BGR pixel type used by opencv if not explicitly chosen differently)

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the high level abstractions OpenCV provides and use them. Then you won't need 14 (buggy) lines of code to do what a single statement does (as @Miki correctly points out) correctly and with much better performance.

Comment: Actually, I am a new learner for OpenCV. All the program I have done are on the Matlab. So I just try some easy codes to get familiar with it. Thanks for the help from all of you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put correct type with `at<>` operator. Your PNG image has to be converted to 8UC1 to then use `uchar` type to access each pixel. I suppose your image has 3 channels, so you only iterate over 1/3 of the image. Also, I suggest you to use `ptr<>` operator in rows loop and then access to pixel as an array.

```
Mat M;
cvtColor(I, M, CV_BGR2GRAY);

// M is CV_8UC1 type
for(int i = 0; i < M.rows; i++)
{
    uchar* p  = M.ptr<uchar>(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < I.cols; j++)
    {
        p[j] = LUT[p[j]];
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** you should use [cv::LUT](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab55b8d062b7f5587720ede032d34156f) instead of doing it yourself.

```
cv::Mat lut(1, 256, CV_8UC1);
for( int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) 
{
    lut.at<uchar>(0,i) = uchar(255-i);
}
cv::LUT(M, lut, result);
```

Comment: LUT is a poor choice, even if you reuse the OpenCV implementation instead of reinventing the wheel. A lookup for each pixel will never perform as well as a simple arithmetic or logical operation, and definitely won't vectorize as well. Not to mention that it really obscures what the algorithm really does.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have figured the problem out with your help. :)